# How do I filter a dataframe for the condition where values are returned if two previous values in the data are less than the third value in the data?

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a set of data in a dataframe and I need to look for a period of time in which sales decreased for two consecutive quarters, then I need to look for the period where sales increased for two consecutive quarters.

I've listed a subset of the data below for reference.

```
              Sales in Millions
     Year1Q1  15
     Year1Q2  13
     Year1Q3  16
     Year1Q4  14
     Year2Q1  12
     Year2Q2  11
     Year2Q3  10
     Year2Q4  11
     Year3Q1  11
     Year3Q2  10
     Year3Q3  15
     Year3Q4  17
```

As you can see, after Year1Q3, there were two consecutive years of lower sales.  Then, the low sales recover in Year3 with Quarters 3 and 4 due to two consecutive increases in sales.

I would need to query the dataframe to return Year1Q4 and then Year3Q4. Any ideas on how to formulate the query for the dataframe is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be a cool way to do this in pandas but a good method for more complicated operations on dataframes is to write a small function that can be executed on each line of the dataframe, and then to use `df.apply`.

I'm using the column names `quarter` and `sales` for simplicity.

```py
# get a list of all quarters, will make things easier later
quarters = df['quarter'].values.tolist()

# define windowing function
# True = last quarter in a 4 quarter window that matches your criteria
# False = all others
def check_quarter(quarter):
    q_index = quarters.index(quarter)
    window = quarters[q_index-3: q_index+1]
    sales = df[df['quarter'].isin(window)]['sales'].values.tolist()
    if len(sales) == 4 and sales[1] < sales[0] and sales[3] > sales[2]:
        return True
    return False

# assign bools to new column
df['check'] = df['quarter'].apply(check_quarter)

# select quarters
df[df['check'] == True]['quarter']
```